# (PHP) Trying to controll the include function

Tags: php

I am now done making my website dynamic (control multiple pages througe 1 page)
I have template where I have 2 side bars left and right, right for categories, left for the the many pages of each category.
Now using the include function to dynamicly generate the side bars is great,
but i am also using class:current on these side bars so the user can easily detect where he is.
now with the right sidebar there is no problem because if the user is in HTML category it will be highlighted with class:current but will not need to change, because user is still in HTML category.
but if the user switch page the left side bar will stay with the last class:current (for example html intro ), even tho user switched to next page (html basics).
i can only have 1 class:current when using the include function.
how can i controll that?

### the code below is the file that im including to each page dynamicly it is .php file.

```
<div class="sidenav">

        <h3> HTML Collection</h3> 
        <hr class="hr1">

        <a class="current" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = 'html_default.php';"> HTML Intro</a>  
        <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = 'html_editors.php';"> HTML Editors</a>  
        <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = 'html_basics.php';"> HTML Basics</a> 

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="sidenavright">

          <h3> Categories</h3> 
          <hr class="hr1">

          <a  style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = '../javascript/js_intro.php';">   Javascript</a>  
          <hr class="hr1" />
          <a  class="current" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = '../html/html_default.php';">  HTML</a>  
          <hr class="hr1" />
          <a  style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = '../howtomain/howto_default.php';">  HowTo</a>  
          <hr class="hr1" />
          <a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="window.location.href = '../python/python_intro.php';">  Python</a>  
          <hr class="hr1" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
```

Comment: What you posted for code isn't "php", it's HTML with JS. Can you explain why this would be a "php" related question/issue?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Because he is trying to simulate the responsive nature of the site via PHP instead of JS.

Comment: because as i said the code i posted is the .php file i am including for each page.

Answer (score -1):

You should be doing this all though JavaScript really, something like AngularJS, or maybe even use Laravel and it would be very easy to control it in your blade views.

Here’s something you can do however.

From the file where you are including it, define a variable before the include that will allow the include to know what page you’re on.

Like so:

```
$currPage = “page1”;
```

Then in your include, on each  tag, you can programmatically put your current class on using one line if/elses, like so:

```
<a <?php ($currPage == “page1”) ? echo         ‘class=“current”’ : echo ‘’?>>Page 1</a>
```

And repeat for all pages you want.

One line if/elses in PHP go like this:

```
Condition ? //true : //false
```

Good luck

Comment: hey sorry this isn't working for me. unless I made bad syntax

Comment: I edited both the include file and the page itself and its not working, cud u inject ur example to my code to help me get it done?

Comment: @grandel_the_really_old It should work fine. If you are copying and pasting my code, be sure to re-type all the “ and ‘ symbols because my phone actually types incorrect symbols

Comment: There, you see what I mean? They said it isn't working for them and are probably getting errors and don't know what to do about them. Please read [Posting quotes from the mobile app results in smart quotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360502/1415724). I hope you find it useful because I do want to help.